# Como salvar arquivos em um servidor via Java?

Tags: java, json, arquivo, servidor

Preciso salvar um arquivo em um servidor utilizando `Java`. No meu caso, preciso salvar um arquivo `json`. Consigo salvar um arquivo normalmente em meu computador, mas como faço para salvar diretamente em um servidor remoto? Segue abaixo um exemplo que salva um arquivo no meu computador. Minha dúvida é: para salvar este arquivo num servidor remoto, como poderia fazer?

```
public class EstudoJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JSONObject json = adicaoSimplesDeDados ();

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("json//javaJSON.json");
        file.write(json.toString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

        System.out.println(json.toString());

        adicaoDeUmObjeto ();
    }

    public static JSONObject adicaoSimplesDeDados () {
        Carro carro = new Carro();
        carro.setId(1l);
        carro.setModelo("Celta");
        carro.setPlaca("AAA1234");

        //Criacao do objeto carroJson
        JSONObject carroJson = new JSONObject();
        //Insercao de valores do carro no objeto JSON
        carroJson.put("id", carro.getId());
        carroJson.put("Modelo", carro.getModelo());
        carroJson.put("Placa", carro.getPlaca());

        System.out.println(carroJson);
        System.out.println(carroJson.get("Modelo"));

        return carroJson;
    } 

    public static void adicaoDeUmObjeto () {
        Carro carro = new Carro();
        carro.setId(1l);
        carro.setModelo("Ka");
        carro.setPlaca("AAA1234");

        JSONObject carroJson = new JSONObject();
        carroJson.put("Carro", carro);

        System.out.println(carroJson);
        System.out.println(carroJson.get("Carro"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Depende de como você quer fazer isso. Você pode fazer isso usando vários protocolos, entre eles FTP, CIFS (usado pelo Windows para compartilhamento de pastas e arquivos), WebService, NFS, SCP (Copia segura em cima do SSH), entre outros.

Comment: @cantoni Com qual destes protocolos possui uma implementação mais simples?

Comment: Pois é, essa é uma boa pergunta. Vc tá fazendo pra aprender ou resolvendo algo definitivo? Usar FTP, SCP ou NFS, requer que tenha um uma programa rodando no servidor. Já o CIFS requer que vc tenha o SAMBA se quiser usar no Linux. Enfim, creio que o WebService é uma opção que é independente de plataforma e mais condizente com a realidade atual. Entretanto, lembre-se que o ideal é que seja feita uma conexão segura entre o client e o server via HTTPS.

Comment: Para resolver algo definitivo. Entendi, com as suas dicas, vou dar uma pesquisada melhor. Então o melhor caminho é através de WebService?

Comment: @cantoni Estou realizando uma aplicação mobile utilizando `phonegap` para conseguir usufruir do benefício da muti-plataforma, e a troca de dados entre sistemas que estou utilizando será feita com `json`, que pelo que pesquisei é uma boa solução. Ainda não tenho muita experiência com este tipo de abordagem e com isso estou tendo algumas dúvidas, e uma delas, foi esta que fiz.

Comment: Neste cenário Duds, não tenha dúvida: WebService na veia. :-)

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: @EduardoSeixas ainda não :/

Answer (score 1):

Se o programa está rodando em sua máquina e deve salvar um arquivo em uma máquina remota, essa máquina remota deve ter uma forma de acesso como FTP, SSH ou outra forma como citado nos comentários.

Se o programa Java já está no servidor, então é como salvar localmente. Bastando uma interface por exemplo Web (HTML).

Se podem existir dois programas Java, um na sua máquina e outro no servidor, você pode usar Socket ou WebService. Um programa cliente enviaria dados para o programa no servidor que salvaria o arquivo ou se for apenas JSON pode salvar no banco como texto ou objetos normais.
Neste terceiro caso é o que um WebService REST JSON faz.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um web service (rest) e salvar o json em um banco de dados que armazena json, como por exemplo o mongodb.